# Count Rows in VBA going up the Excel Sheet to the Numeric Number while selecting the A Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with two columns. I need to count the rows going up from the selected cell "Kim".

```
  A       B
Names | Numbers 
-------------
2 Steve 109
3 John 107
4 Jerry 356
5 Julie Text
6 Chris Text
7 Doug Text
8 Kim Text
9 Mike 101
```

Doug is the current selected cell. How do I count the rows including Doug through Julie using goin up with using IsNumeric() function to stop at the first numeric, but only count all the Text? Note: the text can vary and may not all be the same. The number of rows of Text and vary also. I only want to count the Text rows.

Comment: It is not clear what you require. Is the result 3 or 4 i.e. you're talking about Kim and Doug? Do you want an equivalent of `=COUNTIF(B2:B9;"Text")`? Either way, be more specific and add the code you've tried. If you need to loop backward, you can try something like this: `For i = 9 To 2 Step-1:' Do your thing: Next i`.

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you add an explanation for example something like this : "_if the selected cell is A5, Julie ... then I want the result is 1 (because the row right above julie is number)_". another example : _"If A6 the selected cell then expected result is 2. If A8 selected then expected result 4. Say, B6 is number, then if A8 selected, expected result is 2"_. Something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code/macro below should achieve what you want. It works, as described by `karma` in the comments, and I think like you intended it with `IsNumeric()` and a loop going up the rows with a while loop.

```vb
Sub iterate_up()

    Dim row
    Dim textcount
    textcount = 0
    
    If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then 'Check that the selected cell is in column A
        row = ActiveCell.row
        
        While (Not (IsNumeric(Cells(row, 2).Value)) And row > 1)
            textcount = textcount + 1
            row = row - 1
        Wend

        Range("C1").Value = textcount

    End If
 
End Sub
```

Currently, it doesn't check, if the selected cell is empty and doesn't count empty cells as containing text. The latter could be achieved by changing the condition for the while loop to `While ((Not (IsNumeric(Cells(row, 2).Value)) Or IsEmpty(Cells(row, 2).Value)) And row > 1)`. Similarly, to check for empty selected cells, the if statement would be `If (ActiveCell.Column = 1 And Not(IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value))) Then`. Also, I didn't know, how the result should be returned, so I just put it in the C1 cell. I hope this is, what you are looking for.

Edit: If you want to select the cell with the first numeric value in column B, you'd have to add `Cells(row, 1).Select` before `End If`.